# DELETE from a Join in SQLite / syntax for IN clause on tuples?

Tags: sqlite

I have a schema which uses a compound primary key to store users and associated data, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    domain integer,
    userid integer,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (domain, userid)
);

CREATE TABLE userdata (
    domain integer,
    userid integer,
    key    integer,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (domain, userid, key),
    FOREIGN KEY (domain, userid) REFERENCES users(domain, userid)
);
```

I cannot make changes to this schema, nor can I opt to use another DBMS.

I want to delete some rows in `userdata`, based on a criterion over users. Conceptually, i'd like to do something like:

```
DELETE FROM userdata
WHERE (domain, userid) IN (
    SELECT domain, userid FROM users WHERE <some condition>
) AND key = some_constant;
```

Or alternatively

```
DELETE ud FROM userdata ud
INNER JOIN users u on u.domain = ud.domain and u.userid = ud.userid
WHERE <some condition over u>
AND ud.key = some_constant
```

But sqlite3 (3.8.2) rejects both forms, the former with

```
Error: near ",": syntax error
```

and the latter with

```
Error: near "ud": syntax error
```

Annoyingly, the `IN` syntax works perfectly well when the join key consists of a single column.

What is the proper syntax or technique for achieving this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a SQLite user but I'd try selecting the ROWIDs to delete in userdata. I mean something like

```
delete from userdata
where rowid in (
    select ud.rowid
    from userdata ud
    join users u on ...
    where condition
)
```

Comment: Using row ID feels like a ugly hack, but well, it does the job.

Comment: I know, but used judiciously in reduced scopes such as this, it can be a handy tool

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt does not work because tuples (or whatever they are called) are not supported by SQLite (supported syntax [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)).

Your second attempt is invalid syntax as there is no JOIN in DELETE statements (maybe as an extension introduced by some DBMS but not in [SQL92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) apparently).

What you can try instead is:

```
DELETE FROM userdata
WHERE domain IN (SELECT u.domain FROM users u WHERE <some condition>)
  AND userid IN (SELECT u.userid FROM users u WHERE <some condition> AND domain = u.domain)
  AND key = some_constant;
```

Comment: I had a hard time deciding between two good answers. While I like this answer for being correct and more pure with respect to relational algebra, I will accept the other one because, although it depends on a hack, it is simpler (thus less likely to be messed up) and apparently results in a slightly better query plan. Thanks still for taking the time to answer !

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you want to delete key from user_data and x,y,z condition on user.

```
DELETE  ud.key FROM    user_data AS ud 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON ud.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE   u.something='condition'
```

Comment: That's not valid SQL for the [DELETE statement](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html); only one table is admitted in the FROM clause.

Comment: Same as with the join, sqlite complains with `Error: near "ud": syntax error`

Comment: b0fh can put your complete query here